# QuickSort Random Pivot Not Sorting

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, quicksort, partitioning

As the title implies, I am currently working on a Java implementation of quicksort. I read in my algorithms textbook (Sedgewick text), that choosing a random pivot reduces the chance that I will get worse case performance when the array is already sorted. When I used the first element(all the way to the left) as the pivot, I consistently received a sorted array. However, when I chose a random pivot, I began to get unsorted nonsense. Can anyone tell me what mistakes I am making? Thank you in advance.

```
static void quickSort(String arr[], int left, int right) {
    if (left < right) {
        int index = partition(arr, left, right);
        quickSort(arr, left, index - 1);
        quickSort(arr, index + 1, right);
    }
}

static int partition(String[] a, int p, int r) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int randomNumber = rand.nextInt(a.length);
    String pivot = a[randomNumber];
    int left = p - 1; // i is index into left side
    // The following for loop maintains these conditions
    // 1. Every element of a[p..i] is less than or equal to the pivot.
    // 2. Every element of a[i+1..j-1] is greater than the pivot.
    // 3. a[r] equals the pivot.
    for (int j = p; j < r; j++) { // j is index into right side
        // Find out which side a[j] goes into. If the left side, then we
        // have
        // to increment the size of the left side and then get a[j] into
        // position i.
        // If the right side, a[j] is already where we want it, so just
        // incrementing
        // j in the loop header suffices.
        if (a[j].compareTo(pivot) <= 0) {
            left++; // a[j] belongs in the left side, so we make it one
                    // larger
            swap(a, left, j);
        }
    }

    // We dropped out of the loop because j == r. Every element of a[p..i]
    // is less than or equal to the pivot, and every element of a[i+1..r-1]
    // is
    // greater than the pivot. If we put the pivot into position i+1, then
    // we
    // have what we want: a[p..i] is less than or equal to the pivot, a[i+1]
    // equals the pivot, and a[i+2..r] is greater than the pivot.
    swap(a, left + 1, r);

    // Return the index of where the pivot ended up.
    return left + 1;
}

// Swap the elements at two indices i and j in array a.
static void swap(String[] a, int i, int j) {
    String t = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = t;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are choosing the pivot randomly from the entire array, when it should be an element of the sublist on which you called partition:

```
int randomNumber = p+rand.nextInt(r-p);
String pivot = a[randomNumber];
```

Once you have chosen the pivot you should swap it with the first or last element of the sublist. This makes it easier to write the partition algorithm.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, I thought that was the issue, but I didn't know how to implement the choosing of a pivot from the sublist rather than the entire array. Thanks!